# OCaml: remove the first element of a list

Tags: list, ocaml, head

I have a list composed by several couples of numbers:

```
[(1,2);(3,4);(5,6);(7,8)]
```

I want to remove the the first element (the head) from the list, so the output should be:

```
[(3,4);(5,6);(7,8)]
```

Someone can help me? I was thinking about this function but it doesn't work:

```
let cut x  = function
[] -> []
| (a,b) -> []
| (a,b)::ris -> ris
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remember, that

```
let f x y = function -> <code>
```

is really a shortcut (or a syntactic sugar), for:

```
let f x y z = match z with -> <code>
```

So, it just cuts the last argument in a function, and automatically matches on it.

Also, when you pattern matching keep in mind, that all expressions in the left side of pattern match should have the same type. Otherwise, compiler may pick a random one, and decide, that all others have the same type, yielding a somewhat confusing error message. The same is true for the right sides of patter match. So, when you see a compiler message, saying that something is not what he has expected, just check this preconditions:

```
| []                 (* is a list, by definition *)
| (a,b) -> []        (* is a pair, by definition of a pair *)
| (a,b)::ris -> ris  (* is a list, by definition of (::) *)
```

If left part works, look at the right.

Also, if you have a variable that you do not need to use, then you should better give it a name starting with underscore, or just an underscore.

```
let cut = function
  | [] -> [] 
  | _::xs -> xs
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this. I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

You could write simple:

```
let cut = List.tl
```

You have little mistake.
Third line should look like

```
| [(a,b)] -> []
```

or

```
| (a,b) :: [] -> []
```

P.S. by the way, this third line is unnecessary. Just remove it.
And delete `x` in first line:

```
let cut = function
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
let tl x = match x with
  | [] -> []  (* or   failwith "empty"  *)
  | ab::ris -> ris
```

Few points:

- `function` takes another argument. Your function already get one arg, so use `match x with` instead.
- You are interested only in the list is empty or has a "tail", so you need not pattern-match its element as a tuple.
- This function is called "tail", in OCaml, known as `List.tl`.